# I18n in a growing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a growing rails app that will support different languages. So when something is implemented there will be new language strings, which will not be translated to all available languages on the spot. Should I check if a language file is complete and when yes, how should I do it? If not, how should I handle a missing string. My Idea was to use English as a fallback locale for all languages and automatically create an issue ticket whenever the Fallback-back-end is hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fallback:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
```

Don't wait for a fallback to occur to know there *is* a fallback.
Have a task that search all of the en i18n, and try to find it in all the languages.

That way you'll find all the missing locales before deploying

Comment: Related to the idea of finding which keys are missing in which language, http://www.localeapp.com lets you visualize this easily.